# Unit testing with assertTrue vs others

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I work in a TDD environment and I use assertTrue a lot whereas there are many other methods, such as assert equals etc. I have a class that I have more than 40 test cases and they are all assertTrue. is this acceptable?

I wanted to ask as a style, is this proper?

any suggestions?

if u think this question is inappropriate let me know i ll delete it.

EDIT:

```
    assertTrue(targetSpecifiers.size() == 2);
    assertTrue(targetSpecifiers.get(0).getPlacementId().compareTo(new BigInteger("1")) ==0);
    assertTrue(targetSpecifiers.get(1).getPlacementId().compareTo(new BigInteger("2")) ==0);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main benefits of using other assertions is that they better communicate intent and are likely to give a more meaningful default message in the event of failure.

e.g.

if you write `assertEquals(2, x)` if `x` is actually 1 then the failure message will be:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<2> but was:<1>
```

which is more helpful than if you write `assertTrue(x == 2)` where all you would see is the `AssertionError` and the stack trace.

This is even more important when you are using TDD because you when you write a failing test first you want to be confident that the test is failing for the reason you are expecting it to and that there is not some accidental behaviour going on.

Answer (score 5):

Where appropriate you should use the correct assertXXX methods as they improve the reporting of failures. For e.g. if you are testing for the equality of let us say 2 string "abc" (expected) and "abxy" (actual), then the use of **assertEquals**

```
assertEquals("abc", "abxy")
```

will provide a better output that is easier to reason about than using the **assertTrue** like below

```
assertTrue("abc".equals("abxy"))
```

NOTE: Also pay attention to where you are specifying the **actual** and **expected** arguments. I see lot of developers not following the convention (junit's convention) that the expected should be the first param to the assertXXX methods. Improper usage also leads to lot of confusion

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that you've got things like:

```
assertTrue(expectedValue.equals(actualValue));
```

That will still test the right thing - but when there's a failure, *all* it can tell you was that the assertion failed. If you used this instead:

```
assertEquals(expectedValue, actualValue);
```

... then the failure will say "Expected: 5; Was: 10" or something similar, which makes it considerably easier to work out what's going on.

Unless you're asserting the result of a method returning `boolean` or something like that, I find `assertTrue` to be pretty rarely useful.

If you could give examples of your assertions, we may be able to translate them into more idiomatic ones.

Comment: I have added an example. THanks.

Comment: All of those examples would definitely be better written with `assertEquals`.

Comment: @mikej yes, i just wrote them with assertEquals as well. but they are valid the way it is. is that correct? valid?

Comment: As Jon's answer has said, it is *valid* the way it is with `assertTrue` in so far as the test will still pass and fail under the same conditions but it's better practice to use the more applicable asserts like `assertEquals` as they will be more helpful if the test fails in the future. If the test fails with the way it is now you're going to have to fire up the debugger or add extra code to the test to find out *why* it is failing. Does that help make it clearer?

Answer (score 2):

These assertions are perfectly valid, but other assertions are easier to read and deliver better failure messages.

I recommend looking at Hamcrest- this provides the most readable form of assertions and failure messages. Your example of

```
assertTrue(targetSpecifiers.size() == 2);
assertTrue(targetSpecifiers.get(0).getPlacementId().compareTo(new BigInteger("1")) ==0);
assertTrue(targetSpecifiers.get(1).getPlacementId().compareTo(new BigInteger("2")) ==0);
```

could be rewritten as

```
assertThat(targetSpecifiers, hasSize(2));
assertThat(targetSpecifiers.get(0).getPlacementId(), equalTo(BigInteger.valueOf(1));
assertThat(targetSpecifiers.get(1).getPlacementId(), equalTo(BigInteger.valueOf(1));
```

or even more succinctly as

```
assertThat(targetSpecifiers, contains(
    hasProperty("placementId", equalTo(BigInteger.valueOf(1)),
    hasProperty("placementId", equalTo(BigInteger.valueOf(2))
);
```

`contains` verifies completeness and order, so this covers all three assertions.